# How to make SwiftUI Canvas to draw top and bottom, like normal ViewController can?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Canvas View as below

```
class Canvas: UIView {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        paths.forEach { path in
            switch(path.type) {
            case .move:
                context.move(to: path.point)
                break
            case .line:
                context.addLine(to: path.point)
                break
            }
        }
        
        context.setLineWidth(10)
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.strokePath()
    }
    
    var paths = [Path]()
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        paths.append(Path(type: .move, point: point))
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        paths.append(Path(type: .line, point: point))
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

class Path {
    let type: PathType
    let point: CGPoint
    
    init(type: PathType, point: CGPoint) {
        self.type = type
        self.point = point
    }
    
    enum PathType {
        case move
        case line
    }
}
```

When I use normal ViewController to wrap it as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let canvas = Canvas()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(canvas)
        canvas.backgroundColor = .white
        canvas.frame = view.frame
    }
}
```

I can draw to the top and bottom of the device as illustrated below

[image]

However, if I wrap it around in SwiftUI as below

```
struct ContentView : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        Canvas()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        uiView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

I can no longer draw over the top and bottom of the device as illustrated below

[image]

How could I change it such that the SwiftUI that it allows me to draw to the top and bottom as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to create using the below by having another wrapper across `Canvas` and use it to have `edgeIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        CanvasView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct CanvasView : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return Canvas()
    }
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        uiView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your SwiftUI view, add the ignoresSafeArea() modifier to your ContentView.

```
var body: some View {
    ContentView().ignoresSafeArea()    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @davidev. Unfortunately, my `ContentView` is `UIViewRepresentative` and not `View`. There's no `ignoresSafeArea() `

Comment: @Elye Any UIViewRepresentable is a View. You don't have ignoresSafeArea because it's available on iOS 14.